# .gitignore does not apply to the .cxx folder

Tags: android, git, github, gitlab, gitignore

I have this .gitignore file in my android project but does not apply to the .cxx folder.
I tested everything but failed.

```
.cxx
app/.cxx
app/.cxx/
```

[image: Android Studio]

[image]

We had trouble working with my colleagues on this project as they changed .cxx files each time the project was build.

How can i fix this problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 4):

I would try something like:

```
*.cxx
app/.cxx/*
```

And before that make sure these files are not already tracked by git, once the file is in, `.gitignore` does not do anything for that file.

Answer (score 1):

```
git rm --cached -r .
git add .
```

This command will ignore the files that have already been committed to a Git repository but now we have added them to .gitignore.